# Why does sql ignores my sentence?

Tags: mysql, sql

I`m making a filter for a real estate business. They have several properties and filters to get them as the customer fetches.

I'm having a problem where after various OR setences Mysql ignores the sentences detailed after this OR.

```
SELECT * FROM props WHERE tipo = 'Casas_Casa' OR tipo = 'Departamentos_Duplex' OR tipo = 'Casas_Chalet' OR tipo = 'Casas Condominio' OR tipo = 'Countries y Barrios cerrados_Casas' OR tipo = 'Countries y Barrios cerrados_Casas' OR tipo = 'PH' AND operacion = 'Alquiler' ORDER BY modif DESC
```

Mysql responds whith all the OR's but does not recognises the 'operacion' value but it does order them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so the `AND operacion = 'Alquiler'` portion of the condition is "tied to" the `'PH'` constraint alone.

Add parentheses to force the correct precedence:

```
SELECT *
FROM props
WHERE (tipo = 'Casas_Casa'
    OR tipo = 'Departamentos_Duplex'
    OR tipo = 'Casas_Chalet'
    OR tipo = 'Casas Condominio'
    OR tipo = 'Countries y Barrios cerrados_Casas'
    OR tipo = 'Countries y Barrios cerrados_Casas'
    OR tipo = 'PH')
AND operacion = 'Alquiler'
ORDER BY modif DESC
```

You can also use `IN` expression to simplify your condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM props
WHERE tipo IN (
    'Casas_Casa'
,   'Departamentos_Duplex'
,   'Casas_Chalet'
,   'Casas Condominio'
,   'Countries y Barrios cerrados_Casas'
,   'Countries y Barrios cerrados_Casas'
,   'PH')
AND operacion = 'Alquiler'
ORDER BY modif DESC
```